# Is there any law that can prevent China from restricting migration of STEM workers to the US?

Tags: united-states, international, china

Is there any law restricting China's ability to prevent [STEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science,_Technology,_Engineering,_and_Mathematics) workers from coming to the US?

Comment: @DaleM for reasons of national security, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

China has no power to ban anyone from entering the United States.  International law cannot stop China from exercising its power to prevent its citizens from leaving China, whether in the case of a STEM genius bound for the United States or in any other case.

Comment: That would be about restricting *emigration*, not immigration. There are plenty of US laws restricting immigration.

Comment: @MartinBonner the question has been substantially changed since I answered it.  The original question title was "Is there international law that can stop Chinese to ban STEM genius to come here?"; the body of the question made it apparent that "here" means the US: "Is there international law that can stop Chinese to ban STEM genius to come here in the US?"

Comment: Ah.  Right!  That makes more sense.  And in fact, it has changed again since my comment.

Comment: @MartinBonner yes, I edited the question myself so it would more accurately reflect the question that I answered and for which my answer was accepted.